# How to scale, rotate and translate a KMZ file in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-maps-api, kmz, google-earth-pro, affine-transformation

I'm a GIS software developer. I would like to adjust manually a KMZ over Google Earth images scaling, shifting and rotating it.

What I'm wondering is a tool like the one in Google Earth to add a raster overlay, but to apply to KML/KMZ polygon, polyline and point tags.

Is there a software to edit KMZ file in this way (elements multiselection and apply scale, shift and rotate)?

Is there a software to import a KMZ, edit it in this way and export again in KMZ?

Or I'm also thinking to develop something myself, but I really don't know where I can start from (Google Maps API?)

Comment: Almost every GIS software has option to georeference raster data. And the KML/KMZ is then only the way to save it. To adjust something by scaling shifting or rotation should be just the first step... then you should alway just marker point to get the correct position. I would recommend to read a little more about georeferensing raster data... (eg. http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/georeferencing_basics.html)

Comment: Dear @wittich who is talking about georeferencing raster data? I need to adjust polygons, points, and polyline tags inside my KML file. You misunderstood my question

Comment: sorry I didn't think that command through I just imagine that you want to fix georeferenced elements by a tool as you described. So maybe a 3D software would fit you needs ...